# Spring OuputStream as File Download?

Tags: java, web-services, spring

I would like to send OutputStream object, which has pdf data, as file to the webbrowser.

The code is as follows.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/issue", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void issue(HttpServletResponse response, TimeStampIssueParam param) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    OutputStream pdfOuput = issue(input);
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    ServletOutputStream respOutput = response.getOutputStream();  
    ....

}
```

The problem is I already have the outputstream, and I do not want to convert it to byte array.

Any comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't: you can only copy an InputStream to an OutputStream. Then, you'll can use: org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(InputStream, OutputStream)

Answer (score 1):

First, I would say it is wrong to say that the OutputStream has any data. A stream just lets the data through to some destination. Sometimes (SocketOutputStream) this destination may be on a completely different computer, and sometimes (ByteArrayOutputStream) it will be closely related to the stream and even obtainable through it. But this is a detail of a specific stream, not something you can count on from an arbitrary one.

So, not knowing exactly where the result of the `issue` method comes from it is hard to provide a solution, but a generic OutputStream is not what it should return.

Guessing that the method generates some PDF data and writes it somewhere via an  OutputStream, then returns the stream:

- If it creates a `File` and the stream happens to be a FileOutputStream, it should return the file, file path or a FileInputStream for the same file instead.
- If it creates eg. a ByteArrayOutputStream, then you already have a byte array, and additionally this stream type has a `writeTo` method that can be used directly to write the data to the ServletOutputStream; `issue` just has to return the stream as the proper type not hiding it behind the general interface.
- For other OutputStream types, well, it depends on what exactly they are.